# Getting innertext from an element just before the span

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I would like to extract the innertext of an `a` element, but not the text within the span. So in the example below just the "Xetra". Is there a way to exclude that with puppeteer? It looks like that:

```
<a href="?notation=1929749" title="+15 Min."> Xetra <span>315.573 Stk.</span> </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
let exchangeRaw = li.querySelector('a');
let exchange = exchangeRaw.childNodes[0].textContent;
```